# List to align, easiest way to realize

Tags: c#, list

I have following list:

> 100 -> 1.0 
>  99 -> 1.1 
>  98 -> 1.1 
>  97 -> 1.2 
>  ... 
>   23-28 -> 5.6 
>  ... 
>  0-5 -> 6.0

On the left side are the maximal reached points, on the right side the grade.
This list contains around 40 different Points -> Grade. So my program is calculating the points of the exam, and in the end it should say 100 Points reached, u got the grade 1.0 ... 3 Points reached -> 6.0 ... 
On my current knowledge, I know only switch case, but I think it's not the best way to realize it.

Comment: Is "5,6" meant to be "5.6" as a single value, or is this something else? You say you have a list - do you have any sort of data structure already in place?

Comment: Its 5.6, i have edited my post. I have only a paper with the list above, I don't have a plan in which way i can structure it, to get an easy access.

Comment: Right. Now, how important is performance here? It's quite easy to write *simple* code to implement this...

Comment: Should be shown in real time, after the points calculated together. 1-2 Sec. waiting time is okay.

Comment: What do you mean by "in real time"? If there really are at most 100 entries in the list, then it's going to be pretty fast anyway... but different options would have different memory and speed costs, and if you were trying to scale to (say) a 0-1million points solution, that would be quite different. How is the list going to be supplied to your code? (Having seen your edit, 1-2 seconds is an *enormous* time in computing. Doing that won't be a problem at all...)

Comment: There will be a datagrid, in the first three columns are the part points / they will be calculated together in column 4, on the 5th column should be now possible to see the actually grade. I mean, in real time, would be great, when the user can see instantly the grade, without have any waiting time, and it will be max. 100 entries or less.

Comment: It looks suspiciously like there's a simple `y=mx + c` you could implement here instead of using the list..

Comment: @Blorgbeard, how should this realizable, as you can see in the list above 99 and 98 points have the same grade.

Comment: @Blorgbeard The coordinates indicate that this is not a linear function. If it was, it would be `y = -x/20 + 6`, but the data point at `x = 23` shows that this is not so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start off with a data structure for the list you have. (This is assuming C# 6, by the way - for earlier versions of C# you wouldn't be able to use an auto-implemented readonly property, but that's about the only difference.)

```
public sealed class GradeBand
{
    public int MinScore { get; }
    public int MaxScore { get; } // Note: inclusive!
    public decimal Grade { get; }

    public GradeBand(int minScore, int maxScore, decimal grade)
    {
        // TODO: Validation
        MinScore = minScore;
        MaxScore = maxScore;
        Grade = grade;
    }
}
```

You can construct your list with:

```
var gradeBands = new List<GradeBand>
{
    new GradeBand(0, 5, 6.0m),
    ...
    new GradeBand(23, 28, 5.6m),
    ...
    new GradeBand(100, 100, 1.0m),
};
```

You'd probably want some sort of validation that the bands covered the whole range of grades.

Then there are two fairly obvious options for finding the grade. Firstly, a linear scan with no preprocessing:

```
public decimal FindGrade(IEnumerable<GradeBand> bands, int score)
{
    foreach (var band in bands)
    {
        if (band.MinScore <= score && score <= band.MaxScore)
        {
            return band.Grade;
        }
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Score wasn't in any band");
}
```

Or you could preprocess the bands *once*:

```
var scoreToGrade = new decimal[101]; // Or whatever the max score is
foreach (var band in bands)
{
    for (int i = band.MinScore; i <= band.MaxScore; i++)
    {
        scoreToGrade[i] = band.Grade;
    }
}
```

Then for each score you can just use:

```
decimal grade = scoreToGrade[score];
```

Comment: Thanks, im gonna try this, but can you explain what means the m behind the decimal value?

Comment: @Matej: It indicates that it's a `decimal` literal rather than `double`.

Comment: @Jon The properties miss a `set` accessor.

Comment: @Dzienny: See the second sentence - this is fine in C# 6.

Comment: I realized it with the scoreToGrade Array, works like i wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<int, double> dictionary =
            new Dictionary<int, double>();

        dictionary.Add(100, 1.0);
        dictionary.Add(99, 1.1);
        //Add more item here

        // See whether Dictionary contains a value.
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(100))
        {
            double value = dictionary[100];
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.0}",value));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: As i showed above, i have for example 28-23 Points with the same grade. So it's not the right solution..

Comment: @Matej: That would be fine - you'd just have `dictionary.Add(23, 5.6); dictionary.Add(24, 5.6);` etc. But there's really no need to use a dictionary when you've got a contiguous set of integer keys starting at 0...